# py2neo Cypher transactions failing

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to batch import millions of nodes through Py2Neo.
I don't know what's faster, the `BatchWrite` or the `cipher.Transaction`, but the latter seemed the best option as I need to split my batches. 
However, when I try to execute a simple transaction, I receive a weird error.

The python code:

```
session = cypher.Session("http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/") #error also w/o /db/data/

def init():
    tx = session.create_transaction()

    for ngram, one_grams in data.items():
         tx.append("CREATE "+str(n)+":WORD {'word': "+ngram+", 'rank': "+str(ngram_rank)+", 'prob': "+str(ngram_prob)+", 'gram': '0gram'}")
         tx.execute()  # line 69 in the error below
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ngram_neo4j.py", line 176, in <module>
    init(rNgram_file="dataset_id.json")
  File "Ngram_neo4j.py", line 43, in init
    data = probability_items(data)
  File "Ngram_neo4j.py", line 69, in probability_items
    tx.execute()
  File "D:\datasets\GOOGLE~1\virtenv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\cypher.py", line 224, in execute
    return self._post(self._execute or self._begin)
  File "D:\datasets\GOOGLE~1\virtenv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\cypher.py", line 209, in _post
    raise TransactionError(error["code"], error["status"], error["message"])
KeyError: 'status'
```

I tried catching the exception:

```
 except cypher.TransactionError as e:
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(e.status)
        print(e.message)
```

But never gets called. (maybe an error on my part?)

Regular insert using graph_db.create({"node:" node}) do work, but are incredibly slow (36hrs for 2.5M nodes)
Note that the dataset consists of a series of JSON files, each with a structure to 5 levels deep. 
I'd like to batch the last 2 levels (around 100 to 20.000 nodes per batch)

--- EDIT ---

I'm using Py2Neo 1.6.1, Neo4j 2.0.0. Currently on Windows 7 (but also OSX Mav., CentOS 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is due to a last minute alteration in the way that Cypher transaction errors are reported by the Neo4j server. Py2neo 1.6 was built against M05/M06 and when a few features changed in RC1/GA, Py2neo broke in a few places.

This has been fixed for Py2neo 1.6.2 (https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/224) but I do not yet know when I will get a chance to finish and release this version.

Comment: I patched it manually, and I'm now seeing the proper error mesages!

Answer (score 1):

What neo4j and py2neo versions are you using?

You should use parameters for your create statements.

Can you check the server logs in `data/logs` and `data/graph.db/messages.log` for errors?

If you have so much data to insert then perhaps direct batch-insertion would make more sense?

See: http://neo4j.org/develop/import

Two tools I wrote for this:

- https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/tree/20
- https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20#binary-download

Comment: default_graph.db/messages.log doesn't have anything. Where can I find data/logs on windows? I'd rather not rewrite all the python files to GEOFF/GraphML, it's 8.5Gb's worth of data... But if it is seriously quicker I'll take a shot at it

Comment: You can just spit out CSV or even just the cypher statements and csv for the params.

Comment: The raw csv-batch-importer can do up to 1M nodes/s.

Comment: How do you make relation in the CSV? Of should I use GEOFF for that?

Comment: you create a second csv with columns for from,to,type,prop1,prop2 see the readme for the batch-importer

Comment: being a pythonista you can also check out this: http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/11/musicbrainz-in-neo4j-part-1.html

Comment: I learned that the logfiles are here: AppData\Neo4j Community